# Sewage smell coming from washer

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I've had this issue since I bought my house.  The house was renovated when I bought it, with new washer/dryer unity (not a high efficiency).  The smell isn't all the time.  Some days there is no odor.  It seems to be more of an issue in the morning.  The washer/dryer is situated in the basement. Is this a plumbing issue that can be easily fixed?  I did notice that, when I pulled the unit out of the closest its in,   there was a vent cover.  When I removed it, there was a PVC pipe extending up, with a cap on top that said "Sure Vent".  Is that normal?  Why would this vent into the room?  I've attached a photo of the setup, if that helps.  Also, the tube from my HVAC condenser pump empties into the drain as well.  The metal tubing on the left side of the photo is just the dryer vent resting against the wall.  Any insight would be helpful!

[image]

Comment: Is the smell coming out of the vent or the drain. Also be sure there is a trap in the drain between the washer and the main drain.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/181168/intermittent-sewage-smell-from-air-ducts/181170#181170

Comment: The smell seems to be coming from both the valve and the washer, but stronger from the valve

Comment: Yes, I thought maybe it was the P-Trap, but without removing drywall I am not sure how to check that.  So, I wanted to try other options first.  But, the washer hose and the HVAC condenser hose both are shoved into the pipe.  Maybe they shouldn't be able to go as far into the pipe as they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Surevent that you see is an air admittance valve, meant to allow air IN to your drain line when water is draining.   This valve helps compensate for the low pressure situation in your pipes.  If there’s no pressure equalization, the rush of draiining water will, “suck,”  connected p-traps dry….allowing for nasty odors to infiltrate your home! .   Mechanical air admittance devices can fail.  I’d suggest installing a, “non-mechanical ,” Studor brand, air admittance valve.
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, I will replace it and see how it does.  The odor does seem to be coming from the valve as well as the washer.  Does the valve need to be affixed anyway (glue or something)?  The way it is installed now, the valve is screwed onto a PVC coupling, which is slid over the pipe.

Comment: @jason You might also consider flushing/inspecting any roof vents that you do have. Partial blockages can affect the venting dynamics leading to intermittent odors. Flushing helped me get rid of intermittent odors.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I replaced the valve and it has cleared up the smell!  Thanks!